# Apache Spark Multiple Aggregations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Apache spark in Scala to run aggregations on multiple columns in a dataframe for example

```
select column1, sum(1) as count from df group by column1
select column2, sum(1) as count from df group by column2
```

The actual aggregation is more complicated than just the sum(1) but it's besides the point.
Query strings such as the examples above are compiled for each variable that I would like to aggregate, and I execute each string through a Spark sql context to create a corresponding dataframe that represents the aggregation in question

The nature of my problem is that I would have to do this for thousands of variables.

My understanding is that Spark will have to "read" the main dataframe each time it executes an aggregation.

Is there maybe an alternative way to do this more efficiently?

Thanks for reading my question, and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you consider caching?

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and cache the data frame after you build the DataFrame with your source data.  Also, to avoid writing all the queries in the code, go ahead and put them in a file and pass the file at run time.  Have something in your code that can read your file and then you can run your queries.  The best part about this approach is you can change your queries by updating the file and not the applications.  Just make sure you find a way to give the output unique names.

In PySpark, it would look something like this.

```py
dataframe = sqlContext.read.parquet("/path/to/file.parquet")
// do your manipulations/filters
dataframe.cache()
queries = //how ever you want to read/parse the query file

for query in queries:

    output = dataframe.sql(query)
    output.write.parquet("/path/to/output.parquet")
```